# Why isn't my get request working when getting a specific item of my database?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get information of a specific itemon my database. For that I'm using `/api/IgnicoesAPI/${id}`, however nothing is showing. Here is what I have:

```
 function getData()
{
    var id = 7019;
     $.get(`/api/IgnicoesAPI/${id}`, function (data) {

             $('#myDiv').append(data.latitude);

       var lista = data.listaOcorrencias;
        $.each(lista, function (ocorrencia, o) {
            console.log(lista);
                         var aux = ocorrencia.fotografia;
                        $.each(aux, function () {
                            //    console.log(aux)
                            $('#myDiv').append('<img src="imagensFogos/' + this + '" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(1)" class="hover-shadow" style="width:70px; height:60px" hspace="4"/>')
                            $('#myDiv').append('<p>Imagem: ' + this + '</p>')

                        });

                    });

      });


}
```

For now I'm using a specific id instead of being dynamic. I've already tried
   `` $.get(`/api/IgnicoesAPI/7019`..., `` and it doesn't work

EDIT: I now want to get images and display them, but again nothing happens

Comment: What steps have you taken to debug this issue so far? Look in the developer tools / console. Do you see any errors? In the network tab, do you see the request being made and a response from the server? Maybe the item is not found or server is just not returning a result (timing out).

Comment: For starters --  `$.get('/api/IgnicoesAPI/${id}'` does not look like a valid `GET` --  Unless your API is set to read that format ..  Should it not look something like `$.get(\`/api/IgnicoesAPI/?id=\` + id + \``?

Comment: @zak that is the route when I do web apis in .net and it works fine. the default routing is api/{controller}/{id}

Comment: @TeresaAlves, can you look into the console if there is any issue with the request? Because if it works for postman, it might be some cors issue that you are facing..

Comment: There are no errors detected, everthing is normal

Comment: Have you tried to `console.log(typeof data)` to see if it is a string or parsed data?

Comment: It returns "object"

Comment: @Zak Note that OP has a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) (see the backticks rather than single-quotes).

Answer (score 0):

Did you try if the API is actually working and is returning data, you can try testing the API using postman.

here is a link to download postman. https://www.postman.com/downloads/

you can send in a get request from postman and test if the api is returning the data. if that works then $.get should also work.

Comment: if it is a get he may just be able to put it in a web browser to see the result. http://myservice/api/IgnicoesAPI/7019

Comment: Yes, the get api/IgnicoesAPI/7019 it is working, but when I used in the fuction above nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

Did you try printing the data as mentioned below:

```
function getData()
{
    var id = 7019;
     $.get(`/api/IgnicoesAPI/${id}`, function (data) {
        console.log(data);

      });


}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you got an output if you write the API-URI with parameter in the Adressbar of the browser, so the next Step is to output the whole data-Object you got as result like this:

```
 function getData(){
    var id = 7019;
     $.get(`/api/IgnicoesAPI/${id}`, function (data) {
       console.log("My Data I recieved",data);
     });
}
```

This way you can check, if data will be returned and if it's had the expected structure. Maybe the result is not like expected, so that no iteration with *each* is possible?!
So please post the result of the above.

Answer (score 0):

Because I only want the information of a specific item I don't the $.each

```
  function getData() {
    var id = 7019;
    $.get(`/api/IgnicoesAPI/${id}`, function (data) 
    {


     $('#myDiv').append(data.latitude);

      });


}
```

It works just fine now